# Create calendar for event using FSCalendar library

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar, xcode8.2, fscalendar

I am using FSCalendar third party library.[FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar)
Please check linked library. I have attached reference of calendar in image.
Question:- 
Create Screen in which past 5 months dates are displayed with maximum day as today and make every Wednesday as preselected.
Preselected date background colour : Green Colour,
Current Selected date background colour : Purple Colour,
Rest date background colour : grey colour.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Where is your attached image.

Comment: @ChiragKothiya Please check image.